# Intuition: 5 regular polyhedra, 6 regular 4-polytopes, and then 3 regular d-polytopes

Tags: undergraduate-education, geometry, intuition

I have struggled to offer an intuitive explanation 
(to U.S. college students)
why the number of regular polytopes in dimension $d$ is:

- $d=2$, number: $\infty$.
- $d=3$, number: $5$, the five Platonic solids.
- $d=4$, number: $6$, with the $24$-cell the polytope with no clear $\mathbb{R}^3$ analog.
- $d \ge 5$, number: $3$, the simplex, hypercube, and its dual the cross-polytope (or orthoplex).

The derivations are convincing without providing clear intuition.
Is there some intuitive explanation, perhaps connected to the maximum volume
of a unit-ball achieved in dimension $5$?

---

[image]

          

<sup>Plot: [Dave Richeson's blog](https://divisbyzero.com/2010/05/09/volumes-of-n-dimensional-balls/), 2010.</sup>

---

(But see [Bill Thurston's remarks on the unit-ball volume](https://mathoverflow.net/a/53130/6094).)

Comment: Cool question, mathematically, not just educationally.  Is there an intuitive rationale for the number of crystallographic space groups by dimension.  Wiki seems to say we don't even know how many there are at dimension 6 or higher.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_group#Classification_in_small_dimensions

Comment: These numbers are obtained as: number of positive-integer solutions to a particular system of inequalities.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schläfli_symbol

Comment: This would be a reasonable question if posted on the usual [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions). If you don't get a good answer here, maybe considering asking over there too.

Comment: @MikePierce: Good point. I'll wait a while.

Comment: Among the "cartoon" T-shirts sold by the AMS is one where, in the middle of a computation, there's "and then a miracle happens".  This is the only intuitive explanation I have for the existence of the 24-cell. I'd be very interested to learn of a better one.

Comment: There is the local requirement that in $n$ dimensional space at least $n$ vertices of a given $n-1$ polytope can touch, "with space left over". That is, the intersection of a  neighborhood of a vertex of the $n-1$ dimensional thing with a sphere must have volume strictly less than ${1\over n-1}$ of a sphere. Is this the kind of thing you're wanting?

Comment: @paulgarrett: Yes. Somehow it should be about how much "room" is available in each dimension.

Comment: Now posted [on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2804942/237), as suggested.